# Como gravar informação lida de um arquivo .csv em uma struct em Linguagem C

Tags: c, struct, csv

Estou precisando abrir um arquivo .csv e salvar suas informações em um array de struct

Preciso que a saída seja:
Código - Região - UF - Data

Mas tá sendo:
CódigoRegião - Região - UFDATA - DATA

Gostaria de saber o que está fazendo a saída ficar errada, segue abaixo o código:

```
typedef struct{
    char Codg[10];
    char Regiao[10];
    char UF[2];
    char Data[10];
    }dados_cov;

int main{

    FILE *file;
    dados_cov D[10];

    file = fopen("COV.csv", "r");

    for(int i = 0;i < 3;i++) //Por algum motivo quando leio o arquivo .csv vem com 3 caracteres aleatórios
        fgetc(file);

    if(file)
        for(int i = 0;i < 10;i++){
            fscanf(file,"%10[^;];%10[^;];%2[^;];%10[^\n]\n",  D[i].Codg, D[i].Regiao, D[i].UF, D[i].Data);
            printf("%s - %s - %s - %s\n", D[i].Codg, D[i].Regiao, D[i].UF, D[i].Data);
        }
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Alguém sabe me dizer o porque de não estar dando a saída esperada?
[image: Saída obtida][image: Arquivo .csv]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Erro do programa**

O erro do seu programa é tratar os dados dentro da `struct` como se fossem `string` sem deixar espaço para o caractere `\0`.

Lembre-se que na `linguagem C` uma `string` é um `array/vetor` `unidimensional` terminado pelo caractere `\0`. Exemplo:

> Isso eh string \0

> Isso eh um array de caractere

> Array de caractere nao eh string

O caractere `\0` indica onde uma `string` termina. Se uma `array` for tratado como `string` mas ele não tiver o `\0` então a linguagem não tem como advinhar onde é seu fim.

Observe:

```
char Codg[10];
```

Aqui temos um `vetor` para armazenar exatamente `10 caracteres` e no seu arquivo `.csv` o código tem exatamente `10 caracteres`, então não haverá espaço para o `\0`. Sem o `\0` você não pode usar este vetor como uma `string` (como você faz no `printf`), pois o programa não tem como saber onde é o final.

Um outro problema é quando você usa o `fscanf` com o argumento `%10[^;];` para ler o código, aqui você está usando este vetor como se fosse uma `string`. Se você está usando como uma `string` então o `fscanf` vai colocar o `\0` no final desse vetor, na posição `Codg[10]`. Repare:

> Codg[0] = 'R'

> Codg[1] = 'O'

> Codg[2] = '2'

> Codg[3] = '1'

> Codg[4] = '/'

> Codg[5] = '0'

> Codg[6] = '1'

> Codg[7] = '/'

> Codg[8] = '0'

> Codg[9] = '3'

> Codg[10] = '\0'

Aqui temos um problema, a posição `Codg[10]` não faz parte do seu vetor (lembre-se que 10 posições é de 0 a 9). O problema disso é que o `\0` está, teoricamente, em uma posição de memória que não é reservada para você e por isso essa área pode ser sobreescrita a qualquer momento (o que seria ruim).

Logo em seguida temos:

```
char Regiao[10];
```

O interessante é que esse vetor é declarado logo após o vetor do código e com isso eles ficam lado a lado, isto é, a posição `Codg[10]` é igual a `Regiao[0]` (`Codg[10]` não faz parte do vetor código, mas a posição `Codg[10]` é o que vem depois da `Codg[9]`, essa sim é o final). Então quando você adicionar algo para `Regiao[0]` então o caractere `\0` do código será perdido. Repare como fica esses vetores depois de ler um conteúdo para `Regiao`:

> Codg[0] = 'R'

> Codg[1] = 'O'

> Codg[2] = '2'

> Codg[3] = '1'

> Codg[4] = '/'

> Codg[5] = '0'

> Codg[6] = '1'

> Codg[7] = '/'

> Codg[8] = '0'

> Codg[9] = '3'

> Regiao[0] = 'N' // Codg[10] = '\0' foi sobreescrito

> Regiao[1] = 'o'

> Regiao[2] = 'r'

> Regiao[3] = 't'

> Regiao[4] = 'e'

> Regiao[5] = '\0' // Indica o final da string

> Regiao[6] = '' // Deixei vazio, mas na realidade terá algum lixo nesse lugar

> Regiao[7] = '' // Deixei vazio, mas na realidade terá algum lixo nesse lugar

> Regiao[8] = '' // Deixei vazio, mas na realidade terá algum lixo nesse lugar

> Regiao[9] = '' // Deixei vazio, mas na realidade terá algum lixo nesse lugar

Repare que o `\0` que indicava o final do código foi perdido. Agora se você usar um `printf` para imprimir o conteúdo do código como se fosse `string` então o programa vai imprimir tudo até encontrar um `\0`, como o `\0` está depois do nome da região então o conteúdo da região também será impresso.

Repare que a diferença fundamental desses dois `vetores` é que um o `\0` fica fora do `vetor` e por isso pode ser sobreescrito enquanto o outro `\0` fica dentro do `vetor` e não pode ser sobreescrito (pode ser sobreescrito manualmente, mas isso não vem ao caso agora).

Para que seu problema seja resolvido é necessário que o `\0` sempre fique dentro do vetor, para fazer isso é só aumentar em `1` o tamanho do vetor, isto é, se uma `string` terá no máximo `65` letras, então seu vetor tem que ter `66` posições (uma a mais para o `\0`). No seu código seria algo assim:

```
typedef struct {
    char Codg[10 + 1]; // Adicionando +1 para o \0
    char Regiao[10 + 1]; // Adicionando +1 para o \0
    char UF[2 + 1]; // Adicionando +1 para o \0
    char Data[10 + 1]; // Adicionando +1 para o \0
}dados_cov;
```

Agora essa parte eu não entendi:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) //Por algum motivo quando leio o arquivo .csv vem com 3 caracteres aleatórios
        fgetc(file);
```

Rodei seu código sem isso e funcionou normal.

Seu código final seria mais ou menos assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char Codg[10 + 1];
    char Regiao[10 + 1];
    char UF[2 + 1];
    char Data[10 + 1];
}dados_cov;

int main(void) {

    FILE *file;
    dados_cov D[10];

    file = fopen("COV.csv", "r");

    /*
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) //Por algum motivo quando leio o arquivo .csv vem com 3 caracteres aleatórios
        fgetc(file);
    */

    if(file)
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            fscanf(file,"%10[^;];%10[^;];%2[^;];%10[^\n]\n",  D[i].Codg, D[i].Regiao, D[i].UF, D[i].Data);
            printf("%s - %s - %s - %s\n", D[i].Codg, D[i].Regiao, D[i].UF, D[i].Data);
        }
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Só observando que o ideal aqui seria um programa que faça o parse do CSV pelo separador e ir fazendo strcat para as strings da estrutura. Não tem como se garantir os tamanhos corretos a partir do CSV, caso algum dos campos mude de tamanho, de forma que o ideal aqui seria não usar char[] para armazenar strings, mas char* ou mesmo implementar a sua dynamic strings library. O parse é relativamente simples porque o CSV tem aeparador de campo e pode ou não usar "" para as strings.